# How i can add phing task for automated parsing my project and cresting a PO for translation?

Tags: parsing, gettext, zend-framework2, phing

How i can add phing task for automated parsing my project and creating a PO for translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xgettext to collect all gettext-translatable strings:

http://sourceforge.net/p/semanticscuttle/code/ci/cb4b0469ca48d9865c8b162c1446d9011adf249b/tree/scripts/update-translation-base.php#l11

```
$ xgettext -kT_ngettext:1,2 -kT_ -L PHP  -o data/locales/messages.po src/
```

Execute that from your phing task.